# Hyper-V上のLinux Mintでマウスポインタが表示されない

Tags: linux, windows

Hyper-V上のLinux Mintでマウスポインタが表示されません。
表示するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

Windows 10 Pro / Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cinnamonの問題のようです。

[ここ](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/87e132b4-8133-4d65-8dd5-845077f35730/hyperv-issue-mouse-pointer-invisible-in-linux-mint-17-run-in-hyperv-of-windows-10?forum=winserverhyperv&prof=required#19f48138-ae06-48d6-9ba2-99c4aad2ca36)を参考にターミナルに以下を打ち込みます。

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

これでカーソルが表示されました。